# Ionic 2 using .ts instead of .js file

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

Currently I started learning `ionic2` and it install `.ts file` for me automatically instead of `.js file`.

May someone guide me how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: what CLI command did you use to create the project?

Comment: only {ionic start myTestingApp --v2}
I didn't start it as --ts

Comment: Thats odd. I would mention that in your question then so people are aware :)

Answer (score 0):

Dont start the project with the `--ts` option

**Edit:**

I just tested `ionic start appName --v2` and it correctly creates a javascript project. The output from `ionic info` is this:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.7
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.25
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.15
OS:
Node Version: v5.10.1
```

Comment: can you post the result of `ionic info` ?

Answer (score 0):

All new Ionic v2 projects started will be TypeScript. Ionic team have removed the option to generate new projects using JavaScript. So there are no further options like --js, --no-ts, or --ts flags because they are no longer relevant as Typescript is a superset of Js

More details are here - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/typescript-project-files-named-js/54674/17

Answer (score -1):

> Ionic 2 using .ts instead of .js file

Quickest way. Rename the `.js` file to `.ts` and then start fixing any errors.

JavaScript is TypeScript so your runtime behavior will not change

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html